# Creating a webpage to load audio file and then display spectrogram of the audio file using web audio

Tags: web-audio-api

I am creating a webpage to load an audio file from my local drive and then display a spectrogram of the audio file. I am trying to do this using web audio API. However, my code does not run and I always get the following error message.

Any suggestion or solution that you could give is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spectrogram</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Spectrogram</h1>

  <form>
    <label for="file-input">Select an audio file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" accept="audio/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <canvas id="spectrogram" width="500" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
    const spectrogramCanvas = document.getElementById('spectrogram');

    // Listen for file selection
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
      // Get the selected file
      const file = fileInput.files[0];

      // Create a FileReader object
      const reader = new FileReader();

      // Listen for the file to be loaded
      reader.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Create an audio context
        const context = new AudioContext();

        // Create an audio buffer from the audio file
        context.decodeAudioData(reader.result, function(buffer) {
          // Create a spectrogram
          const spectrogram = createSpectrogram(buffer, context);

          // Draw the spectrogram on the canvas
          drawSpectrogram(spectrogram, spectrogramCanvas);
        });
      });

      // Read the file as an array buffer
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });

    // Create a spectrogram from an audio buffer
    function createSpectrogram(buffer, context) {
      // Create an offline audio context
      const offlineContext = new OfflineAudioContext(buffer.numberOfChannels, buffer.length, buffer.sampleRate);

      // Create a source node from the audio buffer
      const source = offlineContext.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;

      // Create a analyser node
      const analyser = offlineContext.createAnalyser();

      // Connect the source and analyser nodes
      source.connect(analyser);
      analyser.connect(offlineContext.destination);

      // Start the source node
      source.start(0);

      // Render the audio
      return offlineContext.startRendering();
    }

    // Draw a spectrogram on a canvas
    function drawSpectrogram(spectrogram, canvas) {
      // Get the canvas context
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Get the image data for the spectrogram
      const imageData = context.createImageData(spectrogram.width, spectrogram.height);

      // Draw the spectrogram on the image data
      spectrogram.forEach((value, i) => {
        const j = i * 4;
        imageData.data[j] = value;
        imageData.data[j + 1] = value;
        imageData.data[j + 2] = value;
        imageData.data[j + 3] = 255;
      });

      // Draw the image data on the canvas
      context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```